# Why can't I delete local xib? Please see the screenshot.

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

I selected MainWindow.xib(Russian-Russia) and pressed delete, but nothing happened. But why?
Please see the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove it using the Inspector Panel on the right. Select the XIB and bring up the Inspector Right Panel, select the Localisation you want to remove and press the minus button as shown in the picture to remove the Localisation. Only then will it be removed

[image: Remove Localisation]